# How to make a separate functions on manually (looped) added controls

Tags: c#, windows, forms, button, panel

So basically I used foreach loop to add same layout controls. Now I want to make for example simple + and - function. 2 Buttons 1 textbox with increase and decrease. Now i faced a problem, once I make this functionality all of fields gets the same information. If I increase on panel 1 the "count" on other one it still follows up the last count.

My question would be how to make it separately functioning. Int number is declared globally.

```
        Button plus = new Button();
        plus.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        plus.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        plus.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        plus.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 16.5F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        plus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(50)))), ((int)(((byte)(175)))), ((int)(((byte)(241)))));
        plus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(96, 84);
        plus.Name =  number.ToString();
        plus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 29);
        plus.TabIndex = 15;
        plus.Text = "+";
        plus.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

        Button minus = new Button();
        minus.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        minus.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        minus.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        minus.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 13.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        minus.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(50)))), ((int)(((byte)(175)))), ((int)(((byte)(241)))));
        minus.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter;
        minus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(130, 84);
        minus.Name = number.ToString();
        
        minus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 29);
        minus.TabIndex = 16;
        minus.Text = "-";
        minus.UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;

        TextBox t = new TextBox();
        t.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(165, 84);
        t.Multiline = true;
        t.Name = number.ToString();

        plus.Click += (sender, e) => plus_Click(sender, e,t);
        minus.Click += (sender, e) => minus_Click(sender, e, t);

protected void plus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, TextBox t)
{
    Button plus = sender as Button;
    count += 1;
    t.Text = count.ToString();
}
    
protected void minus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, TextBox t)
{
        Button minus = sender as Button;
        count -= 1;

        if (count <= 0)
            count = 0;

        t.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Make a UserControl that contains two buttons and a TextBox. Add instances of this UserControl to your containers (Panels or whatever). You can add a public Property to the UC that returns the current count.

Comment: @Jimi Can you elaborate ? im new to this world, i tried googling, but it didint helped much.

Comment: What did you google about? Anyway, open up the Project Menu, pick `Add UserControl...`, it will create a designer for your UserControl (similar to the Form Designer). Add two Buttons and a TextBox and perform your operations there. Add a public Property to your UC that returns the current `count` value for that UC. Compile. From the ToolBox, select your UC and add as many copies you need of it to your Panel, Form, other Container. That's all. If you then want to know what is the current value of a specific UC, read the value returned by the public Property you added.

Comment: But i'm adding controls to panel manually(Programmally). It's blank panel before you run the application.

Comment: You can add your UserControls *manually* the same way.